# Strange invocation of Shapiro's lemma

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I'm having trouble understanding a claim in a paper I'm reading.  To avoid having to explain a lot of notation, I'll abstract the claim a bit.  Assume that $G$ is a group with a subgroup $H$.  Also, assume that $M$ and $N$ are $\mathbb{Q}[G]$-modules.  The paper then claims that it follows from Shapiro's lemma (applied to $H_0$) that

$$((\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{H} \mathbb{Q}[G]) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} M) \otimes_{G} N \cong M \otimes_{H} N.$$

I can't seem to figure this out.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: see Brown, Cohomology of groups, chap.III, Cor. 5.4.